# Constructor shall throw IllegalArgumentException (need check before this())

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I want my constructor to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with a self written error message when it is called with wrong arguments.

```
public Card(int top, int left, int right) {
    this(TOP.get(top) + 3 * LEFT.get(left) + 9 * RIGHT.get(right));
}
```

Wrong arguments mean that `TOP.get(top)` (resp. LEFT, RIGHT) is null since the `Map<Integer, Integer>` doesn't contain such an element. The problem is that I can't test for that first since `this()` doesn't allow code before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a helper method that checks the input for you:

```
public Card(int top, int left, int right) {
    this(helper(top, left, right));
}

private static int helper(int top, int left, int right) {
    if (TOP.get(top) == null || LEFT.get(left) == null || RIGHT.get(right) == null)) {  
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return TOP.get(top) + 3 * LEFT.get(left) + 9 * RIGHT.get(right);
}
```